# Из объекта в строчку

Tags: javascript

```
let h = {sdf:22, ff:55};
console.log(h.toString())
```

Возможно из объекта, объект привести в строчку как он есть, чтобы в дальнейшем эту строчку отправить запрос к php и записать как она есть...

Comment: `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) и [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
let h = {
  sdf: 22,
  ff: 55
};

const asString = JSON.stringify(h);

console.log(asString);

const objFromString = JSON.parse(asString);

console.log(objFromString);
```